# adding user data in Facebook app query not running

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

i'm running an app on facebook but there seems to be a problem with getting data from a table, the table has data in it that is added in the index page, and i need to access it elsewhere, problem is, the query doesn't work, here it is, i'm opening the table to see if the user exists, if the user doesn't, then i add them later on:

```
$fb_id=$userdata['id'];
        $querya="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_info.fb_id='$fb_id'";
        $result1=mysql_query($querya);

            if(mysql_num_rows($result1)==0){

                         //add user to table, as they don't exist
                           }
```

what could possibly be the problem with the above? the userdata['id'] does have data, i printed it out and it displayed the user's facebook id, so why isn't anything happening? thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be more explicit in your problem. What *doesn't work*? What does "why isn't anything happening" mean? With only those three lines of code, and your description, I'd tell you it's probably because you aren't using mysql_fetch_row (BTW - you should consider using a different MySQL extension for PHP - although it won't solve your problem). Give a little more detail about the issue. Maybe show your table structure, and an example row from the table.

Comment: thanks, sure thing, i've edited it so that it gives more information, the point is to see if the user exists or not, if they do, then $result1 won't be empty, else it will and hence they'd need to be added, does that help?

Comment: Could you paste a print_r from $userdata? Or maybe put a die right next to the variable $querya with this and paste the result: die($querya);

Comment: I'm more curious about the SQL table structure to be honest. My guess is that you made the column as an INT, which won't work for FB IDs. You either would need to use a BIGINT or a VARCHAR. Could you post the output of running "DESCRIBE TABLE user_info" on your database?

Comment: yeah you're right, i did set the column as an INT, i never knew that it wouldn't work for FB IDs should i set a length when i change it to BIGINT or VARCHAR, or should i leave it blank?

Comment: thanks, i changed it and it worked.where do i tick to show that i've gotten an answer?

Comment: I just submitted my response as an answer. You should see the tick next to it, in the answers section below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using an INT column as opposed to a BIGINT or VARCHAR. Facebook IDs are too long to fit into a traditional 32-bit INT column. If you change your table structure to use BIGINT or VARCHAR (and make sure you index the column if you're going to do lookups like this), you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the query syntax, using vars inside a single quote returns the variable as a string rather than a variable
The query should be:

```
 $querya="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_info.fb_id='".$fb_id."'";
```

Comment: That is only true if the string itself is enclosed in single quotes. He just has single quotes around the variable - the variable would still be replaced in this query.